# Given set of values in excel, how can I find them all in a column?

Tags: excel, select, filter, subset

Given a subset A:

```
selection
1
2
3
4
5
```

of Excel sheet:

```
col1    col2   and so on...
1       kuku 
300     pupu
4       abcd
22      sfds
900     aqww
```

I would like to select "selection" content from the sheet, like we can do in SQL:

```
select * from excel_sheet where col1 == selection
```

How can I do this in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this but it has to be pulled down and across to get all the rows and columns that match

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$6,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$6,$D$2:$D$6,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$6)-1),ROW()-1)),"")
```

Has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Another approach would be to add a helper column to the database and filter on it.

The operation of the formula is as follows (working from innermost to outermost)

```
MATCH($A$2:$A$6,$D$2:$D$6,0))
```

Match normally takes a single lookup value Match(lookupValue,range,options) but can also be used with an array of lookup values in which case it returns an array containing the result of each of the lookup values, in this case for each cell in A2:A6 which when looked up in D2:D6 gives

```
1; #N/A; 4; #N/A; #N/A
```

---

```
ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$6,$D$2:$D$6,0))
```

We don't want to know where the match is in D2:D6, just whether it has been successful or not. ISNUMBER produces

```
true: false; true; false; false
```

---

```
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$6,$D$2:$D$6,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$6)-1)
```

We want to find the rows in A2:A6 where the successful matches occur. If the test fails, the output will just be false so you get

```
2; false; 4; false ; false
```

and subtract one so you get

```
1; false; 3; false; false
```

---

```
SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$6,$D$2:$D$6,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$6)-1),ROW()-1)
```

Row() refers to the row of the cell containing the formula (initially F2) so you get 2, then subtracting 1 from that you get 1. So SMALL will give you the smallest element of the above array: 1. When the formula is pulled down into B3, it will give you the next non-false element in the array: 3.

```
INDEX(A$2:A$6,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$6,$D$2:$D$6,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$6)-1),ROW()-1)),"")
```

Standard use of INDEX to give the nth cell in the range A2:A6. In F2, this is the first cell containing 1. In F3, it's the third cell, containing 4. In G2, the formula is pulled across so it applies to the range B2:B6.

---

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$6,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$6,$D$2:$D$6,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$6)-1),ROW()-1)),"")
```

If the index/match fails because there are no more matches, IFERROR shows an empty cell.

---

These formulae look complicated, but they're built up from patterns which are fairly standard and recognised by the  community of regular Excel users.

The formula could be improved by removing the hard-coding of -1 so it is less vulnerable to insertions/deletions

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$6,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$6,$D$2:$D$6,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$6)-ROW(A$1)),ROW()-ROW(A$1))),"")
```

Comment: Would you be so kind and explain the formula?

Comment: Sorry will be away from computer for a bit but will expand later

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will apply your solution and waiting for your explanation.
My pleasure!

Comment: Have expanded as promised. Please note that D2:D5 should have been D2:D6 to include numbers 1-5.